# How "Malice Ascendant" works?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In Yu-Gi-Oh!, there is a monster effect card called "[Malice Ascendant](https://db.ygoprodeck.com/card/?search=Malice%20Ascendant)", which its effect says:

> During your opponent's Standby Phase, send 1 card from the top of
>   their Deck to the Graveyard for each "Malice Ascendant" in your
>   Graveyard.

I don't understand how this card activate its effect - the following are some examples I think this card works, but, I really not sure:

- Do *(at least one copy)* "Malice Ascendant" must be face-up in the field for activate its effect - while haveing another two copies in the graveyard? - *(for send 2 cards from my opponent's deck to their GY)* or
- If I have 3 copies of "Malice Ascendant" in my graveyard, during the opponent's standby phase, "Malice Ascendant"'s copies will activate and send 3 cards from my opponent's deck to their GY?

Answer (score 1):

The effect of Malice Ascendant activates on the field, during the standby phase.
If you have 2 on the field they will activate one after the other in a separate chain.

Then at resolution it will count the number of Malice Ascendants in your grave and your opponent will have to send that many cards from their deck to the grave.
Note, if you were to chain a card to this effect that sends a Malice Ascendant to the graveyard (including the activated one) then that will count towards the number of cards to mill from the deck.

In general, when a monster does not state otherwise, you can assume it is an effect that only activates on the field.